# WebApi with Linq "Extra content at the end of the document" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, iqueryable, asp.net-web-api

I have the following error when I try to query my MVC 4 WebApi service

```
Extra content at the end of the document

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

55Author Namehttp://images.myserver.com/authorspictures/nophoto.jpg
```

I looked into the Author class generated by Linq To Sql and found out that the next property of the Author object just after the image URL is this one:

```
    [Association(Name = "Author_Quote", Storage = "_Quotes", ThisKey = "Id", OtherKey = "AuthorId")]
    public EntitySet<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
```

My undertanding is that there is some problem when generating the XML for this property  causing the above error. However I don't know how I can prevent that and make it working correctly. Most examples I found regarding webApi were using POCO lists so they can't help me on this matter.

Any advices?

Below is my code

```
public class AuthorController : ApiController
{
    IAuthorRepository repository;

    public AuthorController(IAuthorRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository; 
    }

    [ResultLimit(20)]
    public IQueryable<Author> GetAuthors(){
        return repository.GetAuthors(); 
    }
}



public class DBAuthorRepository : IAuthorRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Author> GetAuthors()
    {
        using (var context = new QuotesDataContext())
        {  
            return context.Authors.ToList().AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that it was caused by deffered loading. So I added the following and now it works.

```
public class DBAuthorRepository : IAuthorRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Author> GetAuthors()
    {
        using (var context = new QuotesDataContext())
        {  
            context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false; // Added this line
            return context.Authors.ToList().AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm getting the above error in mvc4 webapi, form @alexandrekow answer, i found the solution:

```
 entity = new BrewedlifeEntities();
 entity.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; // Added this line
```